# Geometric series: two ways to tackle same problem giving me issues

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I am trying to get a closed form expression for the following sum:

$$x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \cdots + nx^n$$

so by perturbation method:

$$S = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \cdots + nx^n$$

$$xS=     x^2  + 2x^3 + \cdots + (n-1)x^n + nx^{n+1}$$

$$(1-x)S = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n - nx^{n+1}$$

Now here is where it gets weird. The professor writes that this can be simplified to this well-known sum: $1+ x+ x^2 + \cdots + x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Giving us:

$$(1-x)S = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} - nx^{n+1} - 1$$

I see the $-1$ is because there is no $1$ in our sum but can't I do the following:

$$(1-x)S = x(1 + x + x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}) - nx^{n+1}$$

$$(1-x)S = x \left( \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \right) - nx^{n+1}$$

So I went to wolfram to see if this was possible and got a peculiar result when I went to test:

[image]

Now I might be using wolfram wrong but is it fair to assume that these two statements:

1.) $(1-x)S = (1-x^(n+1))/(1-x) - nx^(n+1) - 1$

2.) $(1-x)S = x((1-x^n)/(1-x)) - nx^(n+1)$

are equal? And if not: where did I go wrong to get the second statement?

[image]

Comment: This is quite hard to read. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Indeed, $$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} - nx^{n+1} - 1= x\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} - nx^{n+1}$$ ...and surely you can prove this?

Comment: @Luke I have edited most of the post for you. You can format exponents with \$x^{n+1}\$, add fractions with \$\frac{1}{2}\$, and resize brackets automatically with \$\left( \right)\$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your results are correct, You are just using Wolfram wrong.

Here's the actual output,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$S = x + 2x^2 + \cdots + nx^n$$ implies $$(1-x)S = (x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) - nx^{n+1}.$$  This much is clear for you.  If you do not already know the sum for a finite geometric series, this too can be obtained by the same perturbation method you just applied to $S$.  For instance, let $$G = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n.$$  Then $$xG = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^{n+1},$$ and $$(1-x)G = 1 - x^{n+1},$$ from which it follows that $$G = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad x \ne 1,$$ and in turn, $$S = \frac{(G-1) - nx^{n+1}}{1-x} = \frac{1 - x^{n+1} - 1 + x - n(1-x)x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{x + (nx-n-1)x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Second, judging from the output you obtained from Wolfram Alpha, your input was probably inappropriate.  The triple equals sign `===` is the infix notation for the expression `SameQ[]` in the Wolfram language, and it gives `True` only if the LHS and RHS are **exactly** the same expression.  So, if I were to guess, you might have used the word "same" in your input, rather than "equal to."  Instead of dealing with these subtleties, it is much more meaningful to simply **test** the formula for a few carefully chosen values of $x$ and $n$.  If you really want to, you could also input

```
Sum[x^k, {k,0,n}]
```

or you could even input

```
Sum[k x^k, {k,1,n}]
```

to get the answer to the original question.